# Extract a disk image without diskimagemounter

Tags: disk-utility, parental-controls

I have an account on a school system where they won't allow us to mount virtual images. I can run arbitrary programs as a user, though not as root. I've tried mounting it from the command line using diskutil and hdiutil (or somethings like that), and I have an application to convert it between .iso, .cdr, .dmg, and .img. I don't want to have to use Disk Utility to burn it to a CD each time to open it and don't want to need additional hardware (i.e. a CD-R or flash drive). I just want to get files off it. The particular image is Chrome for Mac.

Answer (score 2):

[Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) allows you to examine the contents of packages and archives, including .dmg files, and extract individual files. Unfortunately,  it may require you to authenticate as an Administrator to do so.

I would advocate caution in proceeding. Be certain you're not circumventing the ***intentions*** of your school's system administrators even if your actions are seemingly *allowed* based on the restrictions imposed.

Comment: Yep, and it doesn't even come in a DMG! :D

Comment: Oh, and they state that their intentions are to prevent us from disabling their filters which keep out pornography and illegal content, which I won't be participating in. The main use is for Steam, Chrome, Adium, the like

Comment: Aw, I tried it and it still gave me the popup requiring an administration password to open disk images. :( Thanks for the try, though.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you.

Comment: It's fine. I probably shouldn't be doing this in theory anyways, but really don't like using an archaic form of firefox (or safari)

Comment: @Andrew Safari and Chrome are based on the same rendering engine **WebKit**. Safari also offers the Web Inspector. Why would you prefer Chrome?

Comment: I am fine with WebKit, I just don't like the fact that the forms on the school computers can't be updated - both Firefox and Safari are at version 4 ATM, which isn't that archaic but means there are security flaws I don't want to deal with. I prefer Chrome and Firefox to Safari anyways because of the sync features.